# Performance issue when right table column specified in where clause of left join query

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016

Please help me to redesign the below query for improving the performance -

```
select
    LT.id,
    LT.SalesAmount,
    RT.DiscountAmount,
    (LT.SalesAmount - isnull(RT.DiscountAmount,0.00)) as FinalAmount
from @LeftTable as LT
left join @RightTable as RT on RT.id = LT.id
where (LT.SalesAmount - isnull(RT.DiscountAmount,0.00)) > 0
```

Note - Above query is not exactly that query which is creating performance issue but i simplified it to explain it better here.

I found that issue is, when we use ISNULL in where clause with right table column i.e., `isnull(RT.DiscountAmount,0.00)`.
So, I am looking for alternate to above query where we can remove `isnull` from where clause.

Input data -

```
declare @LeftTable table (id int, SalesAmount decimal(10,2))
declare @RightTable table (id int, DiscountAmount decimal(10,2))

insert into @LeftTable (id, SalesAmount)
select 1, 10.00
union all
select 2, 20.00
union all
select 3, 50.00

insert into @RightTable (id, DiscountAmount)
select 3, 5.00
union all
select 5, 10.00
```

Output required -

```
id  SalesAmount DiscountAmount  FinalAmount
1   10.00       NULL            10.00
2   20.00       NULL            20.00
3   50.00       5.00            45.00
```

Actual query is like -

```
select
    col1, col2,.....
from Table1 T1
inner join Table2 T2 on T2.id = T1.id
inner join dbo.functionName(@variable1) f1 on f1.id = T2.id
...................
left join (select col1, col2
    from table3 T3
    inner join dbo.functionName(@variable2) f2 on f2.id = T3.id) T4
    ......................
where
    T2.col1 + isnull(t4.col2, 0.0) > 0
    and .................
```

Hope so I have mentioned all details here because that is what I have (Actually my colleague is facing this issue and I am trying to help him).

Comment: @HoneyBadger Not in this case, the OP is not comparing the column from the right table to a constant or a column, but using it in a calculation, handling NULL values properly.

Comment: @Pred, you're right, I was too quick.

Comment: Your original question had to do with performance. There are some good answers here, but none avoids having to use an `is null` or an `or`. If you're getting poor performance because of this particular clause, you might consider dropping in into a table variable or something, then filtering the smaller, condensed version after it's out of the problematic table.

Comment: Thank you @Xedni, Yes, moving right table data to variable table and using variable table as a right table improves the performance drastically. Do we need to use variable table or temporary table? We are trying that we don't have to use any temp table.

Comment: Not necessarily, no. The only reason I suggested it that way was that if you were having issues doing all your work on the live table, it would serve as a lightweight place to store the data in between steps. You could accomplish the same thing with a CTE or derived table, but that might not eliminate the (completely hypothetical) performance issues when accessing the larger table. If you're worried about overhead, but you think you want to go this route, you could use a table variable with no PK. That should be pretty unobtrusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing sub-query with variable table and using variable table to hold sub-query data improves the performance.

This is our approach -

```
declare @xyz table (col1 int, col2 int)

insert into @xyz (col1, col2)
select col1, col2
    from table3 T3
    inner join dbo.functionName(@variable2) f2 on f2.id = T3.id

select
    col1, col2,.....
from Table1 T1
inner join Table2 T2 on T2.id = T1.id
inner join dbo.functionName(@variable1) f1 on f1.id = T2.id
...................
left join @xyz T4
    ......................
where
    T2.col1 + isnull(t4.col2, 0.0) > 0
    and .................
```

Thank you @Xedni for comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, it eliminates the ISNULL function, but it will introduce a UNION like behavior.

```
(
(LT.SalesAmount > 0 AND RT.DiscountAmount IS NULL)
OR (LT.SalesAmount - RT.DiscountAmount > 0)
)
```

Comment: Sorry, query still taking time. I think my question is wrong, It is not about query redesign, there is some other issue. When we move right table data to temp table and add that temp table with left join, it works. Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one easy way:

```
where (RT.DiscountAmount IS NOT NULL AND LT.SalesAmount - RT.DiscountAmount > 0)
OR 
(RT.DiscountAmount IS NULL AND LT.SalesAmount > 0)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will share this approach and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following:

```
;WITH JoinResults AS
(
    SELECT
        LT.id,
        LT.SalesAmount,
        RT.DiscountAmount,
        LT.SalesAmount,
        RT.DiscountAmount,
        LT.SalesAmount - RT.DiscountAmount as FinalAmount
    FROM
        @LeftTable as LT
        left join @RightTable as RT on RT.id = LT.id
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    JoinResults AS J
WHERE
    (J.DiscountAmount IS NULL AND J.SalesAmount > 0) OR 
    J.FinalAmount > 0
```

Comment: Exact query is too big that we afraid moving it to CTE will improve performance. I will share this approach with my colleague. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
declare @LeftTable  table (id int primary key, SalesAmount decimal(10,2));
declare @RightTable table (id int primary key, DiscountAmount decimal(10,2));

insert into @LeftTable (id, SalesAmount) values
       (1, 10.00)
     , (2, 20.00)
     , (3, 50.00);

insert into @RightTable (id, DiscountAmount) values
       (3, 5.00)
     , (2, 25.00)
     , (5, 10.00);

select lt.id, lt.SalesAmount, rt.DiscountAmount, lt.SalesAmount - isnull(rt.DiscountAmount, 0) as net
from @LeftTable lt 
left join @RightTable rt 
  on lt.id = rt.id
where (LT.SalesAmount - isnull(RT.DiscountAmount,0.00)) > 0; 

select lt.id, lt.SalesAmount, rt.DiscountAmount, lt.SalesAmount - rt.DiscountAmount as net
from @LeftTable lt 
join @RightTable rt 
  on lt.id = rt.id
where (LT.SalesAmount - RT.DiscountAmount) > 0  
union all
select lt.id, lt.SalesAmount, null, lt.SalesAmount as net
from @LeftTable lt 
left join @RightTable rt 
  on lt.id = rt.id
where LT.SalesAmount > 0  
  and rt.id is null;
```

Comment: Exact query is too big that defining it two times for `union all` will not improve performance. Please correct me.

Comment: So you think I posted an answer I thought was not correct?